# Red Alert 3 with Steam on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, games, steam

When I am trying to install Command and Conquer Red Alert 3 im getting this error: "Command and Conquer: Red Alert 3 is not available on your current platform."

But I do have CounterStrike working on my ubuntu 15.10....

Does someone know how to install/play Red Alert 3 with steam on Ubuntu (15.10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because the [Red Alert 3](http://store.steampowered.com/app/17480/?l=english) is only built for single OS, whilst CS was built for GNU/Linux as well. [Here you can read about the error](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1539-TDHL-6192&l&l=english). If that happened to you, you have to [run Windows version of steam through wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462030/can-i-play-windows-game-using-wine-and-or-through-steam).